# How can I use Lightning base components in my Salesforce App?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience

I'm attempting to use a `lightning:card` in my own Lightning Component. As far as I can tell from the docs, I should be able to reference the component directly with no additional setup. Here's what I have right now:

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable" access="global" >

  <lightning:card>
    <aura:set attribute="title">
        <lightning:badge label="Hello"/>
    </aura:set>
  </lightning:card>
</aura:component>
```

However, when I try to save this file, I get the following error:

```
Failed to save undefined: No COMPONENT named markup://lightning:card
```

My component is being directly included in a lightning experience page, and isn't part of a standalone application.

If I load `/auradocs/reference.app` from my Salesforce domain, I don't see any `lightning:` components listed (I **do** see `ui:`, `aura:`, `force:` and my own custom components.)

Comment: Are you trying this in Summer '16 or Winter '17?

Comment: Summer '16. Chalk this up to unfortunate timing, I noticed this in the documentation without noticing that it's newly available.

Comment: That happens just about every release, to the best of us. Fortunately, Winter '17 is going to be here soon  It helps to read the release notes when they become available, as it'll help you avoid silly mistakes like that (and get you ready for new features).

Answer (score 4):

After some research, I found the (disappointing) answer that this was due to those components only being available in Winter '17, which the documentation defaults to but isn't available yet for most installs.

I was able to start a new trial with Winter '17 available by signing up [here](https://www.salesforce.com/form/signup/prerelease-winter17.jsp). This creates a new account, so you won't have existing components available, but does allow you to start using these components.